# Git repository on server reverts my changes but has same log as local

Tags: git, ssh, server

I have a really weird issue that I can't seem to resolve, although I've search for 4 hours now.

Basically, I have a Git repository on a server. I managed to clone that repository locally through SSH.

If I make local changes, I can push them to the server. **But the server will revert my changes.**

### Step 1: making local changes

I add a `test.php` file locally. It shows up if I do `git log`.
[image]

### Step 2: pushing my changes

I push my changes to the remote repository. There is no error.
[image]

### Step 3: check the server repository

If I `ssh` onto the server, and do `git status`, it should show no local changes. However, it shows changes to be committed. These changes actually **undo exactly what I just pushed**.
In this case, it will delete the file I just added.
[image]

### Step 4: check log on server

If I run `git log`, I have the exact same log as my local repository.
[image]

I really don't understand what's happening. I can push changes but they're undone as soon as they reach the server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated because this is driving me crazy, as I can't find anyone who has encountered the same issue as me.

Comment: Thanks @RomainValeri. I just checked: there's only `*.sample` files in the `.git/hooks` directory. There is no `post-receive` file at all. Also, this is brand new repository, so I haven't done anything special.

Comment: Misleading comments on my part, I read too hastily I guess, iBug is right on spot.

Answer (score 4):

That's because when pushing, the server only updates its commit history and **index area**, without touching your **working tree**. This way after pushing, your working tree on the server remains at its previous state, while its branch has been updated.

It's generally recommened against pushing to the checked-out branch a non-bare repo, so perhaps pushing to another server (e.g. GitHub) and pulling from there on your server might be a better idea.

If you're sure you're doing everything right on your server, manually run `git checkout -f` everything something's pushed onto it, to ensure its working tree matches its index area.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I was actually looking at making my repository a bare one instead, which should help. I was also thinking of having GitHub as a second remote but not as a "through" repo to my server.

Answer (score 2):

The answer iBug provided was helpful as it explained *why* my changes were being reverted. I tried to make a bare git repo on the server but it didn't help me since I needed the files to actually be present on the server.

Anyway, here is what I did: I **made the remote repo update when changes are pushed to it.**

```sh
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
```

Now, when I push to the server, it keeps the changes and updates its working tree.

I found the solution on [this page](https://git-annex.branchable.com/tips/making_a_remote_repo_update_when_changes_are_pushed_to_it/#targetText=Normally%2C%20pushing%20a%20change%20into,the%20files%20checked%20out%20there.&targetText=Now%20after%20a%20push%20to,working%20tree%20will%20be%20updated.).